# SVG animate only one clip-path element but not the rest

Tags: svg, css-animations, clip-path

I have the following code that works:

```css
.clip-svg {
  clip-path: url(#myClip);
  animation: fadeInAnimation ease 3s;
}
#image-overlay {
  position: absolute;
}
#image {
  opacity: 0.035;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
}
#overlay {
  padding: 10px;
  inset: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
@keyframes fadeInAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img id="image-overlay" class="clip-svg" src="https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:1400/0*kAOAT0_uC42E9V5l" />
    <img src="https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:1400/0*kAOAT0_uC42E9V5l" id="image" />
  </div>
  <svg>
          <defs>
            <clipPath id="myClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
              <polygon points="0,0 .4,0 .4,.4 0,.4"/>
              <circle cx=".2" cy=".42" r=".04"/>
              <circle cx=".4" cy=".2" r=".04"/>
              <polygon points=".6,.6 1,.6 1,1 .6,1" />    
              <circle cx=".8" cy=".6" r=".04"/>
              <circle cx=".6" cy=".8" r=".04"/>
              <polygon points=".6,0 1,0 1,.4 .6,.4" />
              <circle cx=".6" cy=".2" r=".04"/>
              <circle cx=".8" cy=".4" r=".04"/>
              <polygon points="0,.6 .4,.6 .4,1 0,1"/>
              <circle cx=".2" cy=".6" r=".04"/>
              <circle cx=".4" cy=".8" r=".04"/>
            </clipPath>
          </defs>
</svg>
```

It works fine
Here is the link to the CodePen:
https://codepen.io/marceltudor/pen/xxJBqRO

I'd like to animate only one of the four puzzle pieces not all of them.

I tried a direct reference by #id in svg and in polygon

```css
.clip-svg {
  clip-path: url(#myClip);
}
#myFirstSvg #polygon1 {
  animation: fadeInAnimation ease 3s;
}
#image-overlay {
  position: absolute;
}
#image {
  opacity: 0.035;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
}
#overlay {
  padding: 10px;
  inset: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
@keyframes fadeInAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img id="image-overlay" class="clip-svg" src="https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:1400/0*kAOAT0_uC42E9V5l" />
  <img src="https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:1400/0*kAOAT0_uC42E9V5l" id="image" />
</div>
<svg id="myFirstSvg">
          <defs>
            <clipPath id="myClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
              <polygon id = "polygon1" points="0,0 .4,0 .4,.4 0,.4"/>
              <circle cx=".2" cy=".42" r=".04"/>
              <circle cx=".4" cy=".2" r=".04"/>
              <polygon points=".6,.6 1,.6 1,1 .6,1" />    
              <circle cx=".8" cy=".6" r=".04"/>
              <circle cx=".6" cy=".8" r=".04"/>
              <polygon points=".6,0 1,0 1,.4 .6,.4" />
              <circle cx=".6" cy=".2" r=".04"/>
              <circle cx=".8" cy=".4" r=".04"/>
              <polygon points="0,.6 .4,.6 .4,1 0,1"/>
              <circle cx=".2" cy=".6" r=".04"/>
              <circle cx=".4" cy=".8" r=".04"/>

            </clipPath>
          </defs>
</svg>
```

I tried as well the  tag in svg

```css
.clip-svg {
  clip-path: url(#myClip);
}

#image-overlay {
  position: absolute;
}

#image {
  opacity: 0.035;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

#overlay {
  padding: 10px;
  inset: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

@keyframes fadeInAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img id="image-overlay" class="clip-svg" src="https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:1400/0*kAOAT0_uC42E9V5l" />
  <img src="https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:1400/0*kAOAT0_uC42E9V5l" id="image" />
</div>
<svg>
          <defs>
            <clipPath id="myClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
              <polygon points="0,0 .4,0 .4,.4 0,.4">
          <animate id="animation1"
             attributeName="opacity"
             from="0" to="1" dur="1s"
             begin="0s;animation2.end" />
    <animate id="animation2"
             attributeName="opacity"
             from="1" to="0" dur="1s" 
             begin="animation1.end" />
        </polygon>
              <circle cx=".2" cy=".42" r=".04"/>
              <circle cx=".4" cy=".2" r=".04"/>
              <polygon points=".6,.6 1,.6 1,1 .6,1" />    
              <circle cx=".8" cy=".6" r=".04"/>
              <circle cx=".6" cy=".8" r=".04"/>
              <polygon points=".6,0 1,0 1,.4 .6,.4" />
              <circle cx=".6" cy=".2" r=".04"/>
              <circle cx=".8" cy=".4" r=".04"/>
              <polygon points="0,.6 .4,.6 .4,1 0,1"/>
              <circle cx=".2" cy=".6" r=".04"/>
              <circle cx=".4" cy=".8" r=".04"/>
            </clipPath>
          </defs>
</svg>
```

But it does not animate the respective polygon.

Ideally I'd like to animate the group of the first polygon and the first two circles, but even to animate the first polygon I can't. Can you please help me on how to animate the first polygon, and just that one not all of the clip-path elements.

Thank you

Comment: Make it a [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  I added the snippets, they are useful. Now I hope it's easier for you or anyone to help me find the solution.

Comment: Not quite minimal.. loose the HTML, HEAD and BODY tags, remove all non essential CSS,  remove as many whitespace as you can, and press that Tidy button in the editor.

Comment: Ok, done, I removed the empty lines, removed the html and head tags and clicked on the Tidy button.

Comment: Isn't [your original image](https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:1400/0*kAOAT0_uC42E9V5l) one image? At first sight I don't see code that creates **4** images

Comment: There are two images with the same source that are overlapping the top one with a low opacity. They the clipath in the svg is cutting out the low opacity image to reveal the normal image underneath. The question is though how to animate only one element of the clip-path, and not the rest of the elements.

Comment: You can animate images clipped with a path; you can not animate clip-paths as if they are individual images

Comment: Thank you can you help me with a simple example?

Comment: No, I am not here to do your job. When you learn coding, start small. Don't try to build the whole thing. In this case limit your code to the IMG and only one SVG circle (or something) as a clip-path.